# JS split regex by two different character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 strings:

```
"test:header_footer"
"test_3142"
```

I want to get array:

```
array = "test:header_footer".split(":") // ['test', 'header_footer']
array2 = "test_3142".split("_") // ['test', '3142']
```

Can I combine this with a regex expression to get the same result?

```
function(s) {
 retutn s.split(/:|_/) // return bad value
}
```

So if string contain `':'` - not separate by second `'_'`

Comment: Your conditions are not regular, therefore *regular* expressions are a poor fit. Instead, first determine if a `:` is present, and then choose the split character accordingly.

Comment: your first string contains both `:` and `_`, how do you decide which one is the delimiter?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein ":" - has priority

Answer (score 1):

You could write a one line method to check for `:` and split based on that condition.

```
var text = "your:string";
var array = text.split(text.indexOf(":") >= 0 ? ":" : "_"); // ['your', 'string']

var text2 = "your_string";
var array2 = text.split(text.indexOf(":") >= 0 ? ":" : "_"); // ['your', 'string']

var text3 = "your:other_string";
var array3 = text.split(text.indexOf(":") >= 0 ? ":" : "_"); // ['your', 'other_string']
```

This will check for `:`, if that is found then split by `:`, otherwise split by `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `includes` method on your String to determine if there's a `:` present. If there *is* split the String by the colon, otherwise split the String by the underscore.

```
split_string = s => s.includes(":") ? s.split(":") : s.split("_");
```

```js
//test strings
let str = "my:string_demo",
  str2 = "my_string_demo",
  str3 = "myString:demo_thing",
  //string function
  split_string = s => s.includes(":") ? s.split(":") : s.split("_");


console.log(
  str, split_string(str)
);
console.log(
  str2, split_string(str2)
);
console.log(
  str3, split_string(str3)
);
```